# Mocking inner object call

Tags: python, mocking, python-3.4

Here is my code that is under test -

```
client = Client('http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx')
client.service.CelsiusToFahrenheit('1234')
```

Here is my test -

```
@patch.object(Client.service, 'CelsiusToFahrenheit')
def test_method_call(self, mock):
    converted = convert('1234')
    mock.assert_called_once_with('1234')
```

I'm trying to mock using `patch.object` the `CelsiusToFahrenheit()` method call, however I keep getting exceptions that say `AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'service'`. I've tried many variations and everything fails with similar exceptions.

My goal is to ensure `CelsiusToFahrenheit()` gets called with the appropriate parameter, 1234. How can I make this happen?

Alternatively, are there any other ways of achieving this? Would using `Mock` instead be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're patching the wrong thing, it looks like you don't need `patch.object` but just the usual patch.

```
@patch('path.where.Client.imported.Client.service.CelsiusToFahrenheit')
def test_method_call(self, mock):
    converted = convert('1234')
    mock.assert_called_once_with('1234')
```

Additionally make sure the path through which the `CelsiusToFahrenheit` method is imported (via `convert` here) is where you're patching, as opposed to the path where the `CelsiusToFahrenheit` method is *defined* (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)).

Comment: I'm messing around with the paths, but can't seem to pinpoint it. Is there an easy way to determine exactly the path I need?

Comment: It's not easy.. I still get it wrong sometimes too.  Read through the link "where to patch"

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't upvote you since I don't have enough rep.